# How's Hegel's conception of Geist different from the bible's conception of the holy spirit?

Tags: hegel, christianity

I was seeing a documentary on Christianity, in it many times the word "Holy spirit" was mentioned with subtext that it was something written in the bible. I had previously heard Hegel came up with a related sounding idea of the >>Heiliger Geist<<. Do these two ideas have any relation to each other? What exactly are the differences?

Comment: Relevant: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14533/what-did-hegel-mean-by-world-spirit

Comment: The Holy Spirit in Christian theology is an aspect of the triune God along with Jesus and the Father (this is trinitarianism, which most Western Christians are. I'm not sure what roll the Holy Spirit plays in unitarianism, but it's probably similar). The Holy Spirit is said to indwell Christians and to be responsible for communicating between God and man and is responsible for prompting the conscience.

Comment: See [Geist: Hegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geist#Hegelianism): "*Geist* is a central concept in Hegel's *The Phenomenology of Spirit*. According to Hegel, the *Weltgeist* ("world spirit") is not an actual object or a transcendental, Godlike thing, but a means of philosophizing about history." "Hegel's description of Napoleon as "the world-soul on horseback" (*die Weltseele zu Pferde*) became proverbial. The phrase is a shortened paraphrase of Hegel's words in a letter written in 1806: 'I saw the Emperor – this world-soul – riding out of the city on reconnaissance.' "

Comment: We can hardly assert that Napoleon was an incarnation of Holy spirit...

Answer (score -1):

First taking a look at the meaning of Holy Spirit.

From [Take Our Word For It](http://www.takeourword.com/Issue082.html#Spotlight)

> *Holy Ghost* is used interchangeably with *Holy Spirit* today and is a much older term.  It dates back to Old English, where the form was
> *hálga gást or hálig gást*, composed of two distinct words, as today.  The first record of the term comes from about 900 in *Halsuncge* in
> *Durham Ritual*: "*Ic eow halsige on fæder naman, and on suna naman..and on ðæs halgan gastes.*"  ...
>
> The etymology of *holy*, *spirit*, and *ghost* are also of interest as
> a part of this discussion.   *Holy* is, as might be expected based on
> the etymology of *Holy Ghost*, an Old English term.   Its form in
> about 1000 A.D. was *halig* and it derives from the Indo-European root
> *hailo*- or *kailo*- "free from injury, whole", whence comes also English *hale* as in "hale and hearty".
>
> ... *spirit* was initially used to translate Greek *pneuma* and Hebrew
> *ruah*, starting in about 1250, and all versions of the Bible from Wyclif onward use *spirit* in translation of the Greek and Hebrew.
> Prior to the Middle Ages, however, *ghost* was used.   It comes from
> the Indo-European root *gheis*- "fear or amazement", and there are
> descendants of that root in most of the Germanic languages, all of
> them possessing similar meanings.

From [Of Spirit: Heidegger and the Question](https://books.google.gg/books?redir_esc=y&id=TLlpmZUQ2OkC) by J. Derrida, page 98, translating Martin Heidegger

> The burning up is the radiance of a reddening  glare.  What burns
> itself up is Being-outside-itself  (*das Ausser-sich*) which illuminates
> and makes  shine, which also, however (*indessen auch*), can  devour
> tirelessly and consume everything up to  and including the white of
> the ash (*in das Weisse  der Asche verzehren kann*).
>
> "The flame is the brother of the palest" is what  we read in the poem *Verwandlung des Bösen*  (*Transmutation of the Evil One*).  Trakl
> envisages  "spirit" on the basis of this essence which is named  in
> the originary meaning (*in der ursprünglichen  Bedeutung*) of the word
> "*Geist*," for *gheis* means:  to be thrown (*aufgebracht*), transported [or
> transposed, deported: *entsetzt*, again -- and I  believe this is the
> most determining predicate],  outside itself (*ausser sich*).

So here we have a process like a burning, a shine, a transport outside itself.  What might be interpreted as a shock, out of one's mind (a transport), a gasp (same root), a very much spirited emotional state.  Definitely a lot going on, in a process.

And then we have Hegel taking this idea of process to the scale of the Absolute.

From [Nietzsche, Philosopher, Psychologist, Antichrist](https://books.google.gg/books?id=Rw4u68fxYQMC&pg=PA239), page 239

> Both [Hegel and Nietzsche] postulated a single basic force whose very
> essence is to manifest itself in diverse ways and to create
> multiplicity—not *ex nihilo*, but out of itself.
>
> Hegel found the prototype of such a creative force in the Christian
> conception of the Holy Spirit, which he interpreted in his own
> characteristic fashion: God the Father must, without any external
> compulsion, become incarnate, embody himself, and thus become God the
> Son; in the Holy Spirit, however, God the Father and God the Son are
> one.  Thus the spirit is a unity that is not an “inert simplicity,”
> nor an “unstained self-identity,” but essentially a process.

Comment: The quote from Take Our Word For It doesn't add anything to the answer. The etymology of the word tells nothing about the concept.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I guess I'm focusing on the process aspect, as dynamic intelligence or burning life force. The Catholic encyclopedia says the [Holy Ghost](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07409a.htm) is a Person, which relates less easily to the idea in the Hegel quote.

Comment: But the question was about the difference between Hegel and the Holy Spirit, so if a quote from the Catholic encyclopedia suggests that the two ideas aren't relatable, that's the answer.

Comment: My problem with this answer is rather that a secondary source which makes claims about what Hegel might have thought about the holy ghost in relation to father and son is not quite adding something to the difference between the Catholic holy ghost and Hegelian absolute Geist or world spirit.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Inasmuch as a person is/has a spirit it make the two ideas relatable.

Comment: Yet you are not answering the question which was asked.

Comment: @DavidGudeman "*Do these two ideas have any relation to each other?*" - They relate insofar as they are both characterised as activity/process, agency.

Comment: 99% of the things that people talk about are characterized by activity-/process, agency. I don't know anything about Hegel, but if you need to suppress the personhood of the Holy Spirit to draw a similarity, you are stretching the point beyond breaking. It's like someone asking how Aristotle is related to karma and you make some stretched point that makes no sense to anyone who knows that Aristotle is a person, not a principle.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity#Holy_Spirit_in_the_New_Testament) : "*another argument from the Cappadocian Fathers ... reasoned that ... the Holy Spirit has the same relationship to God as the spirit within us has to us.*" - which supports the endeavour to analyse what 'spirit' means in general.

Comment: The Holy Spirit is briefly discussed here : [In Our Time - The Nicene Creed](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/b008jglt) at 36 minutes in.  Significant emphasis on 'mystery'.